# Jquery correct way to find element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button as follows:

```
 this._BtnCancel.ID = "btnCancel";
 this._BtnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
 this._BtnCancel.Click += new EventHandler(btnCancel_Click);
```

While populating a text box, I want to access this button and on its click do something as follows. What is the correct way to find the button?

```
 $("#" + txtBox).parent().parent().find('.btnCancel').click(function () {   $(".ui-menu-item").remove(); });
```

Comment: Please post your html structure.

Comment: Watching what are you doing, You are setting ID and text but you are not setting the class .btnCancel to this button?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, Your button ID and button Class are same.

If you want to use ID

```
 $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
   //
  });
```

If you want to use Class

```
$(".btnCancel").click(function () {
  //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use find function, just use the right selector:

```
$("#btnCancel").click(function () { $(".ui-menu-item").remove(); });
```